# Discord.js issue with maps

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I store some data for like this

```
client.data = new Map()
client.data.set("001", {
    content: "test"
})
```

Is there a possible way to generate a number from 001 to 999 that doesn't exist in the maps?

For example I have maps like this

```
Map(2) { '002' => { content: 'test' }, '001' => { content: 'test' } }
```

And i wanted the generated number to be 003 since 001 and 002 is used
what I have tried:

```
const data = Array.from(client.orders.keys())


const nums = [];
let i = 1;

while (i < 999) {
    if (!data.includes(i)) {
        nums.push(`${i}`.padStart(3, '0'));
    }

    i++;
}
nums[0]
```

but `nums[0]` gives 001 which already exists in the maps

Comment: you "stole"? lol

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca ahaha you're right. my bad.

Comment: but @Laif's train of though wasn't completly wrong. Since `data` is not an array it does not have a `includes` method. You should instead look at methods for javascript [`Maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca can you see my edited question? I edited it with `Array.from(client.orders);` but it gives me number 001 even if number 001 exists as a map

Answer (score 0):

Doing it for a `"001"` string is a bit difficult.
I'll assume you're using it as integer. Like:

```js
let Data = new Map();
Data.set(1, { content: "Beep boop" });
```

Now we should be able to do this

```js
let AddElement = (DataMap, Value) => {
    for(let a = 0; a < 999; a++){
        let dummy = DataMap.get(a);
        if(!dummy){ //If no value for a -- The key dosen't exist
            DataMap.set(a, Value); //Setting new value because the key is unique
            break; //Stop the loop to avoid repeated data
            //We can also use return since it's a function
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can call the function anywhere.
For test let's use this example

```js
let Data = new Map();
Data.set(1, { content: "Beep boop" });
//^^^Old code
AddElement(Data, { content: "PP Poo Poo" });
```

Comment if you get any errors